# Distribute msvcr120.dll with a c++ app that was created with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, installation

I have created a c++ app using visual studio 2015. My distribution package requires files msvcp140.dll and vcruntime140.dll in order for my app to run correctly on another pc. According to https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/distributable-code-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-rc-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-sdk-rc-includes-utilities-buildserver-files/:

> Visual C++ Runtime Files Subject to the License Terms for the
>   software, you may copy and distribute with your program any of the
>   files within the followng folder and its subfolders except as noted
>   below. You may not modify these files. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist

Since both of the above files reside in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist I can distribute these two files with my executable.
However  I also need file msvcr120.dll due to a precompiled third party library that I also use. This file resides in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools.
I know that there is an option by using specific inno setup file to check which vc++ redistributables are needed and to installed the correct ones. However for the time being I just need to include the relevant dll in my executable setup package.
So my question is whether I'm allowed to distribute msvcr120.dll with my package as well?

Comment: As far as I know yes. You need that .dll in your package, otherwise on the windows machines that do not have redistributables your app won't work

Comment: @Ispas Claudiu. Thanks for the response. I know that this file is needed , my question is whether is allowed by microsoft terms since msvcr120.dll does not reside in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist

Comment: Technically the 3rd party library author/vendor should have provided you with *all* the executable files you need to use the library.  They probably didn't, relying on you to add the missing pieces.  Which isn't difficult, you should use the vcredist installer.  Don't rely on a random file you found, you can't be sure that it isn't a special build.  That technicality however gets to be less technical as of recent, Microsoft is removing the vcredist installers for old versions from their download site.  So best to stay ahead of that future problem and notify the 3rd party.

Comment: @Hans Passant. You are correct. The library is openssl from Shining Light Productions web site. When I searched the library install folder I found that it contained this file. So is it ok to include this specific file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have VS 2013 and you can find the msvcr120.dll file under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC120.CRT, for the detail information, please check this: [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah(v=vs.120).aspx)

If you do not install the VS 2013, their DLLS are also available as stand-alone redistributable packages from the Microsoft Download Center.

Refer to [Distributable Code for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 SDK (Includes Utilities & BuildServer Files)](https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/distributable-code-microsoft-visual-studio-2013-microsoft-visual-studio-2013-sdk-includes-u-2/) and you should be able to distribute the  msvcr120.dll file from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC120.CRT.